# How to build a sequence based on timestamps ocurrences with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, process, data-visualization, analysis

I'm working primarily with Python on a Database with 17.000.000 records for 2.800.000 unique ID's. Each ID represents an event of a shipping process, and all instances have: ID, EVENT, TIMESTAMP (Datetime). There is an event that usually but not always starts the sequence and there are multiple outcomes, i.e delivered, returned, etc.

My goal in this is to find the most common path each ID takes, meaning, what is the order of events that occur and get the bottlenecks in the process.

Is there any visualization tool I can use with Python that has this structure built into it? 
How would you recommend I approach this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer for Python, but given the question, I think there is a better way to perform such analysis.

I do not know if you have ever heard of Process Mining. But I think it is the perfect thing to use in your case. Basically, process mining consists of analyzing the flow of a process. I have worked with differen tools, some of them are:

- Disco
- ProM (Open Source)
- Celonis

Basically, all you need to do is define what is the ID (you already have it), then choose which columns represents the timestamp (you already have it) and the name of the event (you also have it).

Any of those tools will be able to give you back a perfect analysis of your flow. Which is the most common path, the average time for each event, etc.
If you add more attributes, it can even return what is the reason to follow one path or another based on those attributes.

Comment: Are you sure Disco is open source? I'm aware that this is Process Mining but I'm aming at apply it using Python, that way it's easier to implement with free software.

Comment: Sorry, the Open Source one is Prom (I just updated it). I think Disco has a free version, but with limited rows (10.000 I believe) so that is for sure not enough for you!

Comment: If you need to use Python, I guess Pandas is the best option. I tried to work with Process Mining libraries previously in Python and it is impossible.

Comment: For python, you can look at http://pm4py.org/, else, there is a great suite of package in R : https://www.bupar.net/